# How to call a Databricks Notebook using Power Automate

Tags: powerbi, azure-databricks, power-automate

Where I work is not allowed to schedule a notebook and have access to power automate so I would like to know how to call a notebook databricks through power automate? so I can schedule this flow in the power automate and run the notebook at the time I want...

I have the connection token access data in databricks, I just need to know how to create a flow with this information in power automate.

Comment: Here's an example of how you call the REST API https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56153505/calling-databricks-notebook-using-databricks-job-api-runs-submit-endpoint you just use a REST API call in power automate

Answer (score 2):

I reproduced the above scenario by following the **@Nick.McDermaid**'s comment and got the below results.

For sample I have used a **when a HTTP request is received** and after that I have used http post to call the REST API of Notebook.

You can use your trigger as per the requirement.

This is my flow:

[image]

Give the following:

**URI**: `https://<databricks-instance>.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/jobs/runs/submit`

**Headers**: **Authorization** `Bearer <databricks PAT token>`

**Body**:

```
{
  "existing_cluster_id": "<cluster id>",
  "notebook_task": {
    "notebook_path": "/Users/User_name/Notebook_name"
  },
  "run_name": "run name"
}
```

**Execution**:

[image]

**Job run:**

[image]

Comment: Works, tks @rakesh-govindula

Comment: @AndreLopes - Thanks for the confirmation. You can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.